# I am trying to scrape multiple pages using beautfiul soup but the code keeps returning the same data for every page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, data-analysis

I am trying to scrape the special offers on the steam website using Python and beautiful soup. I am trying to scrape data from mutiple pages using a for loop. I have attached the Python code below. Any help is really appreciated. Thanks in advance.

```
 game_lis = set([])

    for page in range(0,4):
        page_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/specials#p=" +str(page)+"&tab=TopSellers"
        #print(page_url)
        steam_games = requests.get(page_url)
        soup = BeautifulSoup(steam_games.text, 'lxml')
        s_game_offers = soup.findAll('a', class_='tab_item')
        print(page_url)

        for game in s_game_offers:
            title = game.find('div',class_='tab_item_name')
            discount = game.find('div',class_='discount_pct')
            game_lis.add(title.text)
            print(title.text+":"+discount.text)
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: It doesnt return the same for me

Comment: @HamBurger - It returns the same output for me..The length of the set remains 43..Even If i loop through  8 pages..The same data gets replaced in the set..Can you share your output if you don't mind..?

Comment: @ErmiyaEskandary,The data returned is same for every loop..The size of the set remains constant irrespective of the number of times the loop run..For example,In each page 15 games are listed,So if the loop is run for 3 pages,then it should return 45 games..But In my case it just returns a constant set of game list and adds it to the set,The size of the set is 43

Comment: @Sairam Hm, do you mind please adding actual vs expect output + the actual question to the post, please?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The page is loaded from different URL via JavaScript, so `beautifulsoup` doesn't see it. You can use next example how to load different pages:

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

api_url = "https://store.steampowered.com/contenthub/querypaginated/specials/TopSellers/render/"

params = {
    "query": "",
    "start": "0",
    "count": "15",
    "cc": "SK",  # <-- probably change code here
    "l": "english",
    "v": "4",
    "tag": "",
}

for page in range(0, 4):
    params["start"] = 15 * page

    steam_games = requests.get(api_url, params=params)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(steam_games.json()["results_html"], "lxml")
    s_game_offers = soup.findAll("a", class_="tab_item")

    for game in s_game_offers:
        title = game.find("div", class_="tab_item_name")
        discount = game.find("div", class_="discount_pct")
        print(title.text + ":" + discount.text)

    print("-" * 80)
```

Prints:

```
F.I.S.T.: Forged In Shadow Torch:-10%
HITMAN 2 - Gold Edition:-85%
NieR:Automata™:-50%
Horizon Zero Dawn™ Complete Edition:-40%
Need for Speed™ Heat:-86%
Middle-earth: Shadow of War Definitive Edition:-80%
Batman: Arkham Collection:-80%
No Man's Sky:-50%
Legion TD 2 - Multiplayer Tower Defense:-20%
NieR Replicant™ ver.1.22474487139...:-35%
Days Gone:-20%
Mortal Kombat 11 Ultimate:-65%
Human: Fall Flat:-66%
Muse Dash - Just as planned:-30%
The Elder Scrolls Online - Blackwood:-50%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
The Elder Scrolls Online - Blackwood:-50%
Football Manager 2022:-10%
Age of Empires II: Definitive Edition:-33%
OCTOPATH TRAVELER™:-50%
DRAGON QUEST® XI S: Echoes of an Elusive Age™ - Definitive Edition:-35%
Witch It:-70%
Monster Hunter: World:-34%
NARUTO SHIPPUDEN: Ultimate Ninja STORM 4:-77%
MADNESS: Project Nexus:-10%
Mad Max:-75%
Outer Wilds:-40%
Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor Game of the Year Edition:-75%
Age of Empires III: Definitive Edition:-33%
Ghostrunner:-60%
The Elder Scrolls® Online:-60%
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

...
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.. Could you please tell how we should know, what `params` should be sent to the server?

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam Open Firefox Developer Tools -> Network Tab (or in Chrome) and click on the pagination buttons. You will see the URL along the parameters the page is sending.

Comment: I couldn't find pagination button ;(

Comment: @BehdadAbdollahiMoghadam https://store.steampowered.com/specials#p=1&tab=TopSellers On the bottom `< 1 2 3 4 5 ... >`

Comment: This works perfectly..Many thanks.Can you please explain me the code..Am a beginner so it would be much helpful if you just give me a walkthrough of your code.

Comment: I'm still looking for it , but your answer and comments worth appreciation 

Comment: @Sairam The code is practically same as yours. But instead using your original URL I'm using API URL the page uses to load next pages (the data is send back in the Json form, thus  the `.json()` function.)